# How to stop script on ionicView.leave

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Let me say I have a piece of code like this inside a controller, in an Angular/Ionic app:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      myFunction();
   }, 5000)
});
```

when the user leaves the url mapped to this controller before this 5 seconds from the timeout, the script doesn't stop (and it makes sense). My problem is: `myFunction()` opens an ion-modal.

When the user leaves the page and another one is rendered. But myFunction() will be triggered when the other view is rendered and, then, the ion-modal from the previous view will be shown in the new view. I'm using `setTimeout()` for this example because in my code `myFunction()` is called after an ajax request (and I have no control on the response time).

Is there a way to prevent the current script to execute inside the ionicView.leave event?

EDIT: I found out that $scope has an attribute $$disconnected set to true when the view is left. Do I have to check whether this value is true or not inside my function, to open or not the modal? And, if I have 'n' async functions, do I have to check this inside all my 'n' functions?

EDIT II: I achieved a solution wrapping myFunction() inside a $timeout, assigning its return to a variable and then and on the ionicView.leave, cancelling it:

```
modaltimeout = $timeout(function() { myFunction(); )};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(modaltimeout);
});
```

So, regardless what is inside myFunction(), the promise is cancelled and nothing else happens :-)

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hGGqHyC0X6xYH66uJRyo?p=preview use the menu on the left top. Change to "About" then quickly switch back to "Home". An alert will popup (it would happen also with an ionicModal).

Answer (score 0):

so first name your timeout function:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
  myVar =  setTimeout(function() {
      myFunction();
   }, 5000)
});
```

in your controller simple add a

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
     clearTimeout(myVar);
});
```

Then when you leave your view your timeout will be cleared.

EDIT!

you can control when a function is called after a http request by using the .then callback. It will be run after your ajax call has finished. Here is a example.

```
var req = {
   url: 'https://yoururl.com',
   method: "GET",
   headers: {}
}

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){

}).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
    //put code here to run after the http call
})
```

EDIT 2:

in the .then() part of the call back simply check what state is loaded using

`$ionicHistory.currentStateName()`

so it will look like

```
.then(fucntion(data, status, headers, config){
    if($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === "about"){
        //open modal
}
})
```

check to see if you are in the about view. if you are pull up the modal, if not dont. Easy peasy lemon squezzy. See more about checking the state/view here http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/

Comment: I have explained that I'm using the setTimeout only to simulate an async call. The problem is not to clear a timeout, but to "stop" an async flow.

Comment: okay just saw your plunker, let me cook something up for that

Comment: alright the edit is up, that solution should work. so when the call comes back you can just see if you are in the about state or not and respond appropriately.

Comment: Gonna take a lot Jess! The thing is, I didn't want to wrap the myFunction() call inside a timeout (either native setTimeout or Angular's $timeout), but it seems to be the only one way to cancel a promise with the tools the framework gives.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your check to handler:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {...}
```